# features' range in logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, classification, normalization, transformation, logistic-regression

I use logistic regression. We know that it is a supervised method and needs calculated feature values both in training and test data. There are six features. Although the functions produce these features’ values are different and their maximum value can be 1, there are four features (both in training and test data) that have very low values. e.g. they range between 0 and 0.1 and are never 1, even more than 0.1!!!. Thus these features’ values are very close to each other. Other features are distributed normally (they range between 0 and 0.9). So the difference between these two kinds of features is high, I think this causes trouble in learning process for logistic regression. Am I right?! Does it need any transforming/normalizing these features? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In short: you should normalize your features prior to training. Typically - so each is either in some range (like [0,1]) or is whitened (mean 0 and std 1).

Why is it important? In order to make "small" features important LR will need very high weights in this dimension. However, you will probably use **regularized LR** (typically L2 regularized) - in such case it will be very hard to assign high values to these vectors, as regularization penalty will force model to rather choose equally distributed weights instead - thus **use normalization**. **However** - if you fit LR **without any regularization, then there is no point in scaling** (up to numerical errors) as LR does not depend on the choice of scaling (the solution should be exactly the same)

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful answer. I use Weka for classification. What normalization method do you suggest? I am a newcomer in machine learning. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: subtract mean value of each feature from each instance of that feature and then divide the result with feature's standard deviation.